# How to update database but only if there was changes made?

Tags: php, laravel

Im making "Update profile" page and there is fields which are Optional and can leave them blank. What is the best way to make this all? If I change name and leave "address" example so it updates name, but address leaving blank. If updating both then both updates? Here is the code example:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|min:5',
        'telegram' => 'max:255',
        'discord' => 'max:255'
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->telegram=$request->telegram;
    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a handy `isDirty()` method on Models, so you can simply check that and update if required:

```php
$user = auth()->user();

$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->telegram = $request->input('telegram');

if ($user->isDirty()) {
  $user->save();
}
```

Complete documentation is available here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes

Answer (score 0):

You may confuse your users if you specify a field as `optional` but then choose to ignore empty values. Using your example, lets imagine a user has previously provided an `address` but then decides to remove their `address`. They clear the `address` field, save the form, are shown a `success` response and their `address` is still there. What gives?!

If you specify a field as `optional`, allow it to be cleared.

That said, in answer to your question, if you want to remove empty values so that they are not used to overwrite existing values, you can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```php
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|min:5',
        'telegram' => 'max:255',
        'discord' => 'max:255'
    ]);

    $data = array_filter($request->except('_token'));
    Auth::user()->update($data);
}
```